# Why can't I apply an iterator to a function which accepts a reference of const_iterator?

Tags: c++

Here is the code.

```
#include <vector>

void moveIterator(std::vector<char>::const_iterator& v) {
    v++;
}
int main() {
    std::vector<char> v;
    std::vector<char>::iterator iter = v.begin();
    moveIterator(iter);
}
```

The compilation failed. Here is the error.

```
 candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<char>::iterator' (aka '__normal_iterator<char *, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > >') to 'std::vector<char>::const_iterator &' (aka '__normal_iterator<const char *, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > > &') for 1st argument
```

But it works if I remove `&` in the parameter, as follows:

```
void moveIterator(std::vector<char>::const_iterator v) {  // no &
    v++;
}
```

It seems that I cannot apply an `iterator` to a function which accepts a **reference** of `const_iterator`, why?

Comment: It seems that you think you should be able to apply an `iterator` to a function which accepts a reference of `const_iterator`, why? They are different types.

Comment: Iterator have a very well defined interface, so you normally want to deal with them through templates. Then you don't need to care about what kind of iterator you have, only that it has the functionality that you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason you cannot call `f(std::string&)` with a `std::vector<char>`.

In most implementations,

- `std::vector<char>::const_iterator`,
- and `std::vector<char>::iterator`

are two distinct classes and a conversion from one to a (non-const) reference to the other is not possible.

What you could do is define `moveIterator` as a template:

```
template<class InputIt>
void moveIterator(InputIt& it) {
    ++it;
}

std::vector<int> v;
auto it = v.begin();
auto cit = v.cbegin();
moveIterator(it);  // iterator
moveIterator(cit); // const_iterator
```

Comment: There *is* a conversion from iterator to const_iterator. It doesn't help with references though.

Answer (score 2):

While there is a conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator`, this will require a temporary for the reference to bind to, since the argument is not `const_iterator` itself. As such, a non-const lvalue reference is a non-starter.

`iterator` and `const_iterator` don't even need to be class types. Pointers are iterators too (and are in fact the iterators types of a vector in an optimized build). Consider:

```
void foo(int const*& p) { }

void bar() {
  int i = 0;
  foo(&i); 
}
```

Which produces the exact same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because it would allow all hell to break loose.

Consider this code:

```
#include <vector>
const std::vector<char> doNotChangeMe; // in ROM

void  breakMe(std::vector<char>::const_iterator& v) {
    v = doNotChangeMe.cbegin();   
}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> v;
    std::vector<char>::iterator iter = v.begin();
    breakMe(iter); // imagine this is allowed
    *iter=42; // what happens here?
}
```

It is basically the same reason why `T **` is not convertible to `const T **`.

Answer (score 0):

A `const_iterator` is not a `const iterator` they are distinct types.

> const std::vector::iterator != std::vector::const_iterator